# Using the sum of previous payslips of the same year in salary calculation in Odoo

Tags: odoo

I am using Odoo Payroll 15 with some custom python structures.

I have some type of taxes that have a maximum amount that has to be paid during a year per employee. I want to do a sum of the payslip of that year for a specific line, then I can calculate correctly the amount that has to be paid in that payslip.

I have tried this previously, but it seems like it uses only the current payslip in its calculation:

```py
payslip.sum('THE_TAX', '2022-01-01', '2022-12-31')
```

How can I access previous payslips within the payslip rules? A solution that requires Odoo 16 would work for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an ugly workaround that does give the correct answer:

```py
already_paid = 0.0
for slip in employee.slip_ids:
    for line in slip.line_ids:
        if line.code != "THE_TAX":
            continue
        if line.date_from.year != 2022:
            continue
        already_paid += line.total
```

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between your example and the sum implementation is that your code does not check for payslip states.
This means it does cout all Canceled and unfinished payslips as well.
And the sum implementation counts only payslips with the state in 'done'.

You can add modification of the sum function to the payslip model and call that if you need a different behavior.

The implementation is from v12. Now the hr_payslip is in the Enterprise edition.

```py
class Payslips(BrowsableObject):
    def sum(self, code, from_date, to_date=None):
        if to_date is None:
            to_date = fields.Date.today()
        self.env.cr.execute("""SELECT sum(pl.total) -- this line is different in v12 and v15
                    FROM hr_payslip as hp, hr_payslip_line as pl
                    WHERE hp.employee_id = %s 
                    AND hp.state = 'done'
                    AND hp.date_from >= %s 
                    AND hp.date_to <= %s 
                    AND hp.id = pl.slip_id 
                    AND pl.code = %s""",
                    (self.employee_id, from_date, to_date, code))
        res = self.env.cr.fetchone()
        return res and res[0] or 0.0
```

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/c53081f10befd4f1c98e46a450ed3bc71a6246ed/addons/hr_payroll/models/hr_payslip.py#L300

Edit:
I think it is Odoos bug, the paid state should be included, but it is not. You can use variation of your code; filtering, and mapped functions should make it faster.

I can't test the code:

```py
already_paid = sum(
    employee.mapped("slip_ids")
    .filtered(lambda s: s.date_from.year == 2022 and s.state in ("done", "paid"))
    .mapped("line_ids")
    .filtered(lambda l: l.code == "THE_TAX")
    .mapped("total")
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm on the enterprise edition, would there be a way to do it without modifying any core files?

Comment: Are your payslips in the done state?

Comment: They are in the "paid" state.